# Free service to check my site is alive every n minutes

Tags: website

Is there any free service that can check whether my site is online/offline every n minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host-tracker.com, and 10000000 others.

Just type host tracker in google.com

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.uptimerobot.com/ It is a free uptime monitor with the lowest monitoring interval I could find, you can monitor up to 50 websites at 5 mins interval.